# "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" with npm search

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, windows-10

I have just installed npm 3.10.3 and nodejs v6.3.1 on Windows 10 and when I make my first search with npm I got this message after several minutes:

```
PS C:\Users\ToOoA> npm search express
npm WARN Building the local index for the first time, please be patient
[..................] | : WARN Building the local index for the first time, please be patient
<--- Last few GCs --->

  397899 ms: Mark-sweep 937.3 (1256.9) -> 936.7 (1263.9) MB, 642.4 / 0 ms (+ 402.5 ms in 1423 steps since start of marking, biggest step 13.5 ms) [all
ocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  399012 ms: Mark-sweep 936.7 (1263.9) -> 911.2 (1241.1) MB, 1112.5 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  400136 ms: Mark-sweep 911.2 (1241.1) -> 911.2 (1235.1) MB, 1124.0 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
  401258 ms: Mark-sweep 911.2 (1235.1) -> 911.1 (1229.1) MB, 1121.6 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000000A2635C9E51 <JS Object>
    1: fromString(aka fromString) [buffer.js:194] [pc=000003378855E0D0] (this=000000A263504189 <undefined>,string=00000099AE54CE31 <Very long string[1
96464212]>,encoding=000000A2635D6359 <String[4]: utf8>)
    2: from [buffer.js:94] [pc=000003378855DCF6] (this=000002E9C08A5BB1 <JS Function Buffer (SharedFunctionInfo 000000A2635E3899)>,value=00000099AE54C
E31 <Very long string[196464212]>,encod...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

After googling it, I think it may come from files of a previous install of nodejs not deleted, but I cannot find which ones.

Someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed un npm 4.0.1 :
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14498

```
npm -i npm@4.0.1 -g
npm cache clear
```

Answer (score 2):

Please update to the latest version of npm, where search is now fixed.

npm install -g npm@latest